# /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.22' not found in Aws Lambda Server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, glibc

/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.22' not found (required by /var/task/pyhull/_pyhull.so).
Not able to fix this error on Aws Lambda any help please ?

Comment: Check [this thread in AWS Developer Forums.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=807728)

Answer (score 0):

The `/var/task/pyhull/_pyhull.so` was linked against GLIBC-2.22 or later.

You are running on a system with GLIBC-2.21 or earlier.

You *must* either upgrade your AWS system, or get a different `_pyhull.so` build.

Answer (score 0):

It was related to Lambda Server lib problem.Solved by making zip in aws ec2 server by installing all python libraries there in ec2